# Simpler way to get paragraph column in multipage align-like environment?

Tags: align

### Simpler way to get paragraph column in multipage align-like environment?

[Simpler way to get paragraph column in multipage align-like environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629810/simpler-way-to-get-paragraph-column-in-multipage-align-like-environment)
I am seeking an align-like environment that can contain paragraph-like text columns and can also can overflow onto the next page.

[This page](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11076) showed me how align environments can straddle pages with `\usepackage{amsmath}\allowdisplaybreaks[4]`.  Unlike the tabular environment, however, I can't designate specific columns to behave like paragraphs, with line wrapping.

[This page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426399/wrap-text-inside-align-environment) showed me how wrap text within cells using`\parbox[t]{2in}{Some text.}`.  As shown in the MWE below, however, it introduces a lot of extra noise in the code.

**Is there a more streamline way to accomplish both objectives?**

I initially used `longtable`, but ran into a bug where the text after the table overflowed past the bottom margin, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203629/longtable-and-floats-wrong-table-breaks-on-pages-with-floats-part-2/207748).  I applied the patch [here](https://gist.github.com/KmolYuan/183a6443258c13e9afd421f2f8242e04), but the problem persisted.

I then tried the tabular environment, without an enclosing table environment, but it won't span multiple pages.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
\begin{document}

\vspace*{2in}

Pretend that there is lots of text here.

\vspace*{3in}

I present the equation:

\[ a b c = x y z \]

where

\begin{align*}
   a & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   b & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   c & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   x & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   y & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   z & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

**Failed attempts at simplifying `\parbox` command**

I tried to simplify the use of the `\parbox` command by defining
a `\TLpar` command that takes care of all the details.  I wanted
the `\TLpar` command to look up the length `\ParWidth` whenever
`\TLpar` is invoked.  However it only uses the value of `\ParWidth`
at the time that `\TLpar` is defined:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}\allowdisplaybreaks[4]

% Command to put text into top-left-aligned paragraph box
\newlength{\ParWidth}
\setlength{\ParWidth}{4.5in}
\newcommand{\TLpar}[1]{\parbox[t]{\ParWidth}{\raggedright #1}}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{2in}

Pretend that there is lots of text here.

\vspace*{3in}

I present the equation:

\[ a b c = x y z \]

where

\begin{align*}
   \setlength{\ParWidth}{2in} % Doesn't work
   a & = \TLpar{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   b & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   c & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   x & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   y & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\\[0.05in]
   z & = \parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedright The quick brown fox jumped
   over the lazy dogs.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If I define the `\TLpar` command to accept a second argument to specify paragraph width, that works, but I need to provide the argument at every single invocation of the `\TLpar` command.  That's not very streamlined, as the paragraph width doesn't change throughout any single occurrence of the align environment.

Comment: you just need to set the length before the alignment, an alignment cell is a local group so you lose the set value at the `&`

Comment: @David Carlisle: That works!  Thanks!  Would you like to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `align` cell (like a `tabular` cell) is a local group, so your `\setlength` setting is discarded at the first `&` before you actually use it.

Move the `\setlength` to before the `\begin{align}` so that it is in scope for the whole alignment.

Comment: Thank you, David Carlisle!